# Jquery javascript stock quoter how to get company name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am having an issue with getJSON and pulling the company name from the JSON file. the JSON file stores the name as ,"name" : "Facebook Inc". So in my code when i set to

```
var company = date[0].name;
```

This is where the issue is since .name is a keyword. How do i get around this.

Comment: `name` is a keyword? What do you mean?

Comment: Can we see the JSON?

Comment: post your code and JSON

Comment: if you mean `name` is a reserved word, it is not. And this would not be a problem if it was : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pqxt0gve/)

Comment: script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a simple typo :

```
var company = date[0].name;
```

Try this :

```
var company = data[0].name;
```

Comment: Wow, I had to look really close to see this. Nevertheless this is a typo question and should be closed as such. Answering such questions is discouraged. Please V2C

Comment: I voted to close it. I just answered it to give it the solution. Could have comment yep...

Answer (score 1):

Try ...

```
var company = data[0]["name"];
```